# How do I JOIN lines into single line returned from SQL in one column?

Tags: sql

Im trying to run the sql such as:

select 'TransactionId='|| ||',USER_DATA='|| from bla..bla.

the problem here is that the userdata () has very long values and results are shown as in the notepad ( and even very deterioted in excel):

TransactionId=12385031681, USER_DATA=This product

brought to you by
P&G
SMS, < coumn3 > ...bla.bla

Now, i need to fix the value fetched in USER_DATA into one line rather than number of lines.

Can you please advise ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove line breaks with `replace`:

```
replace(replace(USER_DATA,chr(10),''),chr(13),'')
```

Comment: could you please explain the meaning of chr(10) and chr(13) ? and guide if there are any other such types of functions as well ?

Comment: @Ashish: `chr` converts an [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/) to a character.  A google search for "oracle string functions" returns many [good guides](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/).